# Loading data, caching, and saving on dispose

Tags: c#, mysql

I have just finished coding this class that will load all columns in a MySQL database in to a cached `Dictionary<string, string>` which will only be modified on class construction when its populated with the correct data.
I wanted to ask the codereview community their opinions on it, if its a good idea, what are the downfalls of using something like this and how can I improve it to make it better.

I have included the full class below, along with a method that explains a small bit about a part of the class to do with query parameters.

Class:

```
namespace Sirius.Base.Game.Roleplay.Players
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using Other.GameClients;

    public class RoleplayData : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Player _player;
        private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _cachedPlayerData;
        private bool _disposing;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_disposing)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _disposing = true;

                using (var mysqlConnection = Sirius.GetServer().GetDatabaseManager().GetConnection())
                {
                    var saveQuery = "UPDATE `users` SET ";
                    var foreachIndex = 0;

                    foreach (var dataPair in _cachedPlayerData)
                    {
                        foreachIndex++;

                        saveQuery += "`" + dataPair.Key + "` = @" + dataPair.Key +
                                     (foreachIndex < _cachedPlayerData.Count ? ", " : " LIMIT 1");
                        mysqlConnection.AddParameter(dataPair.Key, dataPair.Value);
                    }

                    if (foreachIndex == 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    mysqlConnection.SetQuery(saveQuery, false); // second parameter is to tell it not to clear parameters upon setting new query.
                    mysqlConnection.RunQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Sirius.GetServer().GetLogManager().Error("Error saving roleplay data for " + _player.GetPlayerData().Username + ": " + exception.Message);   
            }
        }

        public RoleplayData(Player player)
        {
            _cachedPlayerData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            _player = player;

            LoadPlayerData(player.GetPlayerData().Id);
        }

        private void LoadPlayerData(int userId)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var mysqlConnection = Sirius.GetServer().GetDatabaseManager().GetConnection())
                {
                    mysqlConnection.SetQuery("SELECT * FROM srp_user_statistics` WHERE `user_id` = @userId");
                    mysqlConnection.AddParameter("userId", userId);
                    var playerTable = mysqlConnection.GetTable();

                    if (playerTable == null)
                    {

                        return;
                    }

                    foreach (DataRow roleplayRow in playerTable.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (DataColumn column in playerTable.Columns)
                        {
                            _cachedPlayerData.Add(column.ColumnName, Convert.ToString(roleplayRow[column]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Sirius.GetServer().GetLogManager().Error("Error during login for user " + userId + ": " + exception.Message);
            }
        }

        private string SelectColumn(string columnName, bool fromDatabase)
        {
            if (_cachedPlayerData.ContainsKey(columnName) && !fromDatabase)
            {
                return _cachedPlayerData[columnName];
            }
            using (var mysqlConnection = Sirius.GetServer().GetDatabaseManager().GetConnection())
            {
                mysqlConnection.SetQuery("SELECT `" + columnName + "` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = @userId");
                mysqlConnection.AddParameter("userId", _player.GetPlayerData().Id);

                var columnValue = mysqlConnection.GetString();
                _cachedPlayerData.Add(columnName, columnValue);

                return columnValue;
            }
        }

        public int SelectColumnAsInt(string columnName, bool fromDatabase)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(SelectColumn(columnName, fromDatabase));
        }

        public void UpdateColumn(string columnName, string newValue, bool inDatabase)
        {
            if (_cachedPlayerData.ContainsKey(columnName))
            {
                _cachedPlayerData[columnName] = newValue;
            }

            if (!inDatabase)
            {
                return;
            }

            UpdateColumnWithNewValue(columnName, newValue);
        }

        private void UpdateColumnWithNewValue(string columnName, string newValue)
        {
            using (var mysqlConnection = Sirius.GetServer().GetDatabaseManager().GetConnection())
            {
                mysqlConnection.SetQuery("UPDATE `users` SET  `" + columnName + "` = @newValue WHERE `id` = @userId");
                mysqlConnection.AddParameter("newValue", newValue);
                mysqlConnection.AddParameter("userId", _player.GetPlayerData().Id);
                mysqlConnection.RunQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here is my `SetQuery` method. As you can see I can prevent it from clearing parameters which I'll have to do with passing false as the second parameter. Otherwise the parameters I previously set would have been wiped and I don't want a hard coded query, especially with that much information or about 20 - 30 columns.

```
public void SetQuery(string query, bool clearParameters = true)
{
    if (_mysqlCommand.Parameters.Count > 0 && clearParameters)
    {
        _mysqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
    }

    _mysqlCommand.CommandText = query;
}
```

Comment: Is this cache for the game server/host or the game client/user/player?

Comment: client/user/player.

Comment: I would save the original values and only change if the value has changed

Answer (score 2):

Do not do this:

```
var saveQuery = "UPDATE `users` SET ";

// ....

foreach (var dataPair in _cachedPlayerData)
{
    saveQuery += "`" + dataPair.Key + "` = @" + dataPair.Key +
        (foreachIndex < _cachedPlayerData.Count ? ", " : " LIMIT 1");
}
```

This is [why StringBuilder() is available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21644889/648075).

---

Moreover, you're constructing your query inside your `using (var mysqlConnection =`. Don't do that; instead do it in advance -- and yes, you can do that even for the parameters, because you could use [`SqlParameterCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.aspx).

And why are you doing `if (foreachIndex == 0) { return; }`? Instead, simply check the `Count` of `_cachedPlayerData` before even beginning to compile your query and opening a db connection etc.

---

Why are you looping though rows when you obviously should only get a single one?

```
foreach (DataRow roleplayRow in playerTable.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in playerTable.Columns)
    {
        _cachedPlayerData.Add(column.ColumnName, Convert.ToString(roleplayRow[column]));
    }
}
```

This way you're hiding possible errors.

---

Don't use `ContainsKey` if you need to retrieve the value from a dictionary, instead [always use `TryGetValue`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382740/648075).

---

I would try to make the logic of `SelectColumn` and `UpdateColumn` more alike.

Also, avoid using the word "Column". Why not simply `SetValue` and `GetValue`? Ditto with the various parameters etc. Move away from thinking about them as columns and instead see them as properties of a class.

---

Receiving a `columnName` and using that in the query is just inviting a [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. Personally I'd avoid using queries and instead rely on an ORM; if you feel that an ORM is too much hassle (even though something like Dapper is really lightweight) I'd would at least urge you to implement checks:

- Is the passed `columnName` a valid one? Create a `User` class where the properties correspond with the columns of that table, and check if the passed name is the same as one of those properties.
- Don't directly use the passed `columnName`; instead use it as a key in a dictionary where the value is the proper column name. Or instead of passing a string, limit it to an enum value.

But IMHO such checks are requiring you to create code that is likely inefficient and ugly, whereas simply using an ORM takes away all that hassle.